# Taxes on selling a house I rented

Tags: united-states, taxes, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, rental-property

I paid $200,000 for a house in 2007. I lived there until 3 years ago, at which point I rented it out because the real estate market was not good. Now, it is able to be sold for $250,000

I understand that if I sold the house and had lived there 2 of the last 5 years, then I would avoid paying capital gains tax on the sale, is this correct?

To complicate matters, my tenants have started acting bad, and I let their contract expire. Due to coronavirus, they asked for an extension to the lease for a month, but I only gave them 1 week, because if I get to next month, I would not have lived in the house for 2 out of the last 5 years. They are now asking for another extension, however, have put themselves in a bad spot by violating lease agreements, etc which is why I did not renew their lease to start with (I considered continuing to lease the property, but have decided it is a good time to sell in that market).

If I have to go through an eviction process which could take months, will this cause me to have to pay additional taxes on the property after a sale? Should I extend the lease to ensure I keep at least receiving payment while they are there? They have never missed a payment so far. This is in the United States.

here is what turbotax says about the tax advantage of selling for less than $250,000 in profit:

> **How do I qualify for this tax break?**
>
> There are three tests you must meet in order to treat the gain from the sale of your main home as tax-free:
>
> - Ownership: You must have owned the home for at least two years (730 days or 24 full months) during the five years prior to the date
>     of your sale. It doesn't have to be continuous, nor does it have to be
>     the two years immediately preceding the sale. If you lived in a house
>     for a decade as your primary residence, then rented it out for two
>     years prior to the sale, for example, you would still qualify under
>     this test.
> - Use: You must have used the home you are selling as your principal residence for at least two of the five years prior to the
>     date of sale.
> - Timing: You have not excluded the gain on the sale of another home within two years prior to this sale.

As of right now, I think I pass this test. I have owned the home for a decade and rented it the last 3 years. It was my primary residence two of the last 5 years (the first two), and I have not taking the gain on anyo other home.

Comment: "I lived there until 3 years ago": even if you moved back into the house *today*, you would have to live there for another 3 years to meet the "3 of the last 5 years" condition. Look at "YYnnn" -> "YnnnY" -> "nnnYY" -> "nnYYY".

Comment: I'm under the impression that the years did not need to be consecutive. Is that incorrect? (and it is 2 of the last 5 years, not 3)

Comment: You already haven't lived in the house for 3 of the last 5 years; it will take at least 3 years to change that, as every year you live there starting now just pushes on of the other years you lived there before off the table.

Comment: In other words, you already owe taxes on a sale that happens today, whether or not you extend the lease.

Comment: My situation in your nomenclature would be "YYnnn"->sale

Comment: OK, with the edit you do appear to still qualify for the tax exclusion.

Comment: Perhaps to clarify, my question really boils down to: If I cannot have the tenant removed by next month and have the house on the market for sale, due to forces outside my control (tenant wont leave/forced eviction), does that nullify my ability to qualify for tax exclusion?

Comment: This isn't as out of your control as you would like it to be. You knew a year ago when you leased the property that the lease would end just before your occupancy exclusion expired, and you could have anticipated difficulty in selling (or at least re-establishing your own residency) in time.

Comment: Is it legal to evict a tenant right now (many states don't permit evictions right now due to COVID)?  Have you started the eviction process?  (If not, I can't imagine you'd get it done in time even in a normal world).

Comment: Consider: You could _live_ in the house while it is waiting for a buyer.

Comment: According to my property manager, they could start the eviction process if necessary. I have no idea what kind of backlog the courts may be in right now, though.